# Drag-and-drop from div with scrollbars - overflow-y scroll VS overflow-x visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've set up jQuery drag-and-drop from a div to another div and it works fine.

However, the source div sometimes exceeds the screen's height so I needed to add a vertical scrollbar to it. Here's where I run into trouble with the infamous overflow-y issue.

The div needs to have overflow-x: visible in order for the dragged elements to be visible as they are moved to the target div. But, when I add overflow-y: scroll or overflow-y: auto to the source div, suddenly overflow-x doesn't work anymore.

I have been to W3 and a few StackOverflow questions, and I realise this is not a bug but intended behavior (although WHY this was intended is beyond me). However, I haven't found a solution that works for me.

I've tried adding a wrapper div to the source div like some answers suggested, and then doing the following:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4vw;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 4vw;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.source {
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 2;
}

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="source">
        <!-- draggable elements go here -->
    </div>
</div>

<div class="target">
    <!-- draggable elements drop here -->
</div>
```

But, despite the source div's overflow being OK now, the wrapper still hides the horizontal overflow. I suppose I could increase the width of the wrapper to full screen and make the background invisible and make everything else on screen have a higher z-index in order to not be behind the wrapper, but that seems like a ridiculously bad solution for such a simple issue.

Can anyone help me here?

If a CSS solution isn't practical, can anyone offer some piece of Javascript that might resolve the problem?

Code sample: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ush466w)

Comment: can you make a fiddle which replicates this issue

Comment: Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9ush466w/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the following. If you want to drag elements and "drop" them on your *battle positions*, you may want to use `helper: "clone"` in combination with `appendTo: "body"` or any other selector which is where your items will be dropped. I've also added `containment: 'window'` and `scroll: false` (not too sure if this last one is what you want).

```
function make_draggable(elem){
    $(elem).draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        cursor: "move",
        helper: 'clone',
        appendTo: 'body',
                    containment: 'window',
        scroll: false,
    });
}
```

There's also been a few CSS fixes so your styles still apply on the draggable clones and your body actually covers the full area (since your only child is positionated absolute, so we need to force `body` to cover the full height/width)

https://jsfiddle.net/9ush466w/6/

EDIT: Adding custom class and removing it on the original element so you can show feedback to the user. https://jsfiddle.net/9ush466w/8/

Comment: Cloning works ok, but I'd rather avoid it if possible. Is there a way to clone and also add some code to have the original element disappear, but reappear if element is dropped outside the target zones? Making it disappear shouldn't be a problem but I'm not sure where I would add this last part.

Comment: I see how you added/removed the additional class to the original element. Just one small issue left - when I replace the `background: #ddd` with `display: none` it doesn't make the element disappear: https://jsfiddle.net/9ush466w/9/ Any ideas? Happy to award the bounty after this is figured out.

Comment: Oh but it is making it disappear haha. You're just seeing the element from below instead. Here, try using `visibility: hidden;` instead so you can see it is in fact applying. When using display none, you're hiding that element, but the element right beneath is stacking the exact same position, so it seems like nothing happened.

Comment: Ohhhh silly me. That's right. Awarding bounty now. EDIT: awarding bounty in 20 hours because SO won't let me do it now :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not exactly an answer to your question but you are making the items draggable. Looking at your sample, I think you should look into connect lists:

[jqueryui connect lists documentation](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists)

This allows you to take an item from one list, and drop it into another.

Here is a demo jsfiddle I found:

[connect lists fiddle demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/phpdeveloperrahul/Hu39L/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this fix. I edited your function see below. I added "containment" option on draggable.

```
function make_draggable(elem){
        $(elem).draggable({
            revert: "invalid",
            cursor: "move",
            containment: ".unit-holder-middle" 
        });
    }
```

Is this what you want? see this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9ush466w/2/

Comment: I want the opposite :) In your example the draggable elements can't even leave the box, I need them to leave it (working in my version) AND be visible (not working in my version).